# How can I use docker volume with ubuntu image to access a downloaded file from AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, dockerfile

I want to copy a file from AWS S3 to a local directory through a docker container.
This copying command is easy without docker, I can see the file downloaded in the current directory.
But the problem is with docker that I don’t even know how to access the file.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR "/Users/ezzeldin/s3docker-test"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y awscli
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
CMD [ "aws", "s3", "cp", "s3://ezz-test/s3-test.py", "." ]
```

The current working folder that I should see the file downloaded to is `s3docker-test/`. This is what I'm doing after building the Dockerfile to mount a volume myvol to the local directory

```
docker run -d --name devtest3 -v $PWD:/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data ubuntu
```

So after running the image I get this:
`download: s3://ezz-test/s3-test.py to ./s3-test.py`
which shows that the file `s3-test.py` is already downloaded, but when I run `ls` in the interactive terminal I can't see it. So how can I access that file?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are overriding containers folder with your empty folder, when you run `-v $PWD:/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data`.

Try to simply copy the files from container to host fs by running:

```
docker cp \
  <containerId>:/Users/ezzeldin/s3docker-test/s3-test.py \
  /host/path/target/s3-test.py
```

You could perform this command even on downed container. But first you will have to run it without folder override:

```
docker run -d --name devtest3 ubuntu
```

Comment: But this path `/host/path/target/` does not exist

Comment: You should specify the path, where you want to store your file. Exactly the same as with `cp` command.

Comment: For example, you want your file to appear at `~` folder, then run `docker cp <containerID>:/Users/ezzeldin/s3docker-test/s3-test.py ~/s3-test.py`